# How to remove a div if only has a one element

Tags: jquery, removeclass

How to delete parent div if remove all specific div in parent div?

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/iurcudan/xzhaB/1/ for example

```
 $("button.removed").click(function(){
 event.preventDefault();
     $(this).parents('.categdetn2').remove(); });
```

When delete all div with class "categdetn2" remove parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("button.removed").click(function(){
 event.preventDefault();
 if($(this).parents('.categdet').children('.categdetn2').length === 1)
     $(this).parents('.categdet').remove();
 else
     $(this).parents('.categdetn2').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
 $("button.removed").click(function(){
         $(this).parent().remove();
         var items = $('.categdetn2').length;
         if ( items == 0 ) {
             $('.thcat').parent().remove();
         }
  });
```